# Flags in C/ set-clear-toggle

Tags: c, set, toggle, flags

I am confused as to what the following code does, I understand Line 1 sets a flag, line 2 clears a flag and line 3 toggles a flag;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SCC_150_A 0x01
#define SCC_150_B 0x02
#define SCC_150_C 0x04
unsigned int flags = 0;

main () {
  flags |= SCC_150_A;  // Line 1
  flags &= ~SCC_150_B; // Line 2
  flags ^= SCC_150_C;  // Line 3
  printf("Result: %d\n",flags); // Line 4
}
```

What I don't understand is what the output of Line 4 would be? What is the effect of setting/clearing/toggling the flags on `0x01` `0x02` and `0x04`?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question - what's your problem? What exactly don't you understand?

Answer (score 3):

The macros define constants that each require a single bit to be represented:

```
macro      hex  binary
======================
SCC_150_A  0x01    001
SCC_150_B  0x02    010
SCC_150_C  0x04    100
```

Initially `flags` is 0.

Then it has:

1. Bit 0 set by the bitwise OR.
2. Bit 1 cleared by the bitwise AND with the inverse of `SCC_150_B`.
3. Bit 2 toggled (turning it from 0 to 1).

The final result is thus 101<sub>2</sub>, or 5 in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm going to use binary numbers, cause it's easier to explain with them. In the end it's the same with hexadecimal numbers. Also note that I shortened the variable to `unsigned char` to have a shorter value to write down (8 bits vs. 32 bits). The end result is similar, just without leading digits.

Let's start with the values:

```
0x01 = 0000 0001
0x02 = 0000 0010
0x04 = 0000 0100
```

So after replacing the constant/macro, the first line would essentially be this:

```
flags |= 0000 0001
```

This performs a bitwise or operation, a bit in the result is `1`, if any of the input values is `1` at that position. Due to the initial value of `flags` being `0`, this will work just like an assignment or addition (which it won't in general, keep that in mind).

```
flags: 0000 0000
op:    0000 0001
----------------
or:    0000 0001
```

The result is `flags` being set to `0000 0001`.

```
flags &= ~0000 0010
```

Here we've got two operations, first there's `~`, the bitwise complement operator. What this essentially does is flipping all bits of the value. Therefore `0000 0010` becomes `1111 1101` (`0xfd` in hex). Then you're using the bitwise and operator, where a result bit is only set to `1` if both input values are `1` at the specific position as well. As you can see, this will essentially cause the second bit from the right to be set to `0` without touching any other bit.

```
flags: 0000 0001
op:    1111 1101
----------------
and:   0000 0001
```

Due to this, the result of this operation is `0000 0001` (`0x01` in hex).

```
flags ^= 0000 0100
```

The last operation is the bitwise exclusive or (xor), which will set a bit to `1` only if the input bits don't match (i.e. they're different). This leads to the simple behavior of toggling the bits set in the operands.

```
flags: 0000 0001
op:    0000 0100
----------------
xor:   0000 0101
```

In this case the result will be `0000 0101` (`0x05` in hex).

For clarification on the last operation, because I think xor might be the hardest to understand here, let's toggle it back:

```
flags: 0000 0101
op:    0000 0100
----------------
xor:   0000 0001
```

As you can see, the third bit from the right is equal in both inputs, so the result will be `0` rather than `1`.